# Select one row with C# from MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql

I tried MySqlDataReader and any variation of mycmd.ExecuteScalar() but still there is no success. At last I am using MySqlDataAdapter and Fill method and use some if cases and select one row from there. but this makes the code uglier. Here is the example:

```
DataSet tmpDs = new DataSet();
myda.Fill(tmpDs);
if (tmpDs.Tables.Count > 0)
   if (tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
      sonuc = tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0];
```

Is there a better way to select one row from [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill your DS with the following SQL instead of bringing the whole table back.

`SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SomeKey='3' LIMIT 1`

Comment: Yes it is.  The question is about MySQL as well.

Comment: Aye. I missed that last line :)

Comment: I am looking for c# way not sql. but sure that does the job at db side.

Comment: depending on the table size, it would be highly inefficient to bring the entire table back to c# and then choose the row. The optimum was is to select what you want at the source.